# Do we have any native connectivity mechanism to load data to GCP BigQuery , using SSIS

Tags: ssis, google-bigquery

Do we have any native connectivity mechanism to load data to GCP BigQuery ,  using SSIS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We had same requirement of publishing the data from SSIS to BigQuery, we scheduled a shell script which will export the data from SQL server and import in BigQuery via batch import(free) using gcloud utility.

Sample command to load one table:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d reporting -E -Q "select * from location_dim" -o "localtion_dim.csv" -h-1 -s","

gsutil cp C:\Users\Administrator\localtion_dim.csv gs://ssis/

bq --location=US load --source_format=CSV cube_dev.location_dim gs://event-functions-spike/localtion_dim.csv ID:STRING,OFFICE:STRING,MARKET:STRING,COUNTRY:STRING,REGION:STRING,NAME:STRING
```